# Setting skew transformation center

Tags: svg, raphael

For operations such as scale, rotate, Raphael.js provides individual methods, through which we can specify the origin of that transformation.

But for skew there is no method like `ele.skew(xskewAmount,yskewAmount,xtransfOrigin,ytransfOrigin)`.
So I went for the `ele.transform` method, like `ele.transform("m1,0,.5,1,0,0")` to perform a `xskew`. But I can't specify an origin here, so the element is getting translated incorrectly.

I'm need of following info:

- Is there any method through which i can set the transform origin for
  skew
- how much distance will the element be translated(unwantedly), if i
  skew an element. so that i can reposition the element manually.

my code: http://jsfiddle.net/tYqdk/1/

Please note the Skewx button at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 8):

i know this is old but here goes.

[W3C SVG 1.1 - 7 Coordinate Systems, Transformations and Units](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html)

- [7.4 Coordinate system transformations](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#EstablishingANewUserSpace)
- [7.5 Nested transformations](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#NestedTransformations)
- [7.6 The ‘transform’ attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#TransformAttribute)

In section 7.6 they describe the rotation transformation about a point (`cx`,`cy`)

Simply - it's this matrix multiplication:

```
translate(<cx>, <cy>) • rotate(<rotate-angle>) • translate(-<cx>, -<cy>)
```

To apply this to skewX use:

```
translate(<cx>, <cy>) • skewX(<skew-angle>) • translate(-<cx>, -<cy>)
```

- note: these matrix multiplications are described in [7.5 Nested transformations](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#NestedTransformations)

generic matrix
[image]

translate matrix
[image]

skewX matrix
[image]

```js
var skewer = function(element, angle, x, y) {
  var box, radians, svg, transform;
  // x and y are defined in terms of the elements bounding box
  // (0,0)
  //  --------------
  //  |            |
  //  |            |
  //  --------------
  //             (1,1)
  // it defaults to the center (0.5, 0.5)
  // this can easily be modifed to use absolute coordinates
  if (isNaN(x)) {
    x = 0.5;
  }
  if (isNaN(y)) {
    y = 0.5;
  }
  box = element.getBBox();
  x = x * box.width + box.x;
  y = y * box.height + box.y;
  radians = angle * Math.PI / 180.0;
  svg = document.querySelector('svg');
  transform = svg.createSVGTransform();
  //creates this matrix
  // | 1 0 0 |  => see first 2 rows of
  // | 0 1 0 |     generic matrix above for mapping
  // translate(<cx>, <cy>)
  transform.matrix.e = x;
  transform.matrix.f = y;
  // appending transform will perform matrix multiplications
  element.transform.baseVal.appendItem(transform);
  transform = svg.createSVGTransform();
  // skewX(<skew-angle>)
  transform.matrix.c = Math.tan(radians);
  element.transform.baseVal.appendItem(transform);
  transform = svg.createSVGTransform();
  // translate(-<cx>, -<cy>)
  transform.matrix.e = -x;
  transform.matrix.f = -y;
  element.transform.baseVal.appendItem(transform);
};
```

i forked your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j9HFC/11/)

update - a new [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmms5bsb/9/) using built-in SVGMatrix methods. I believe it's easier to read and understand

Comment: is it possible to append just one matrix like doing the multiplication first?

Comment: not sure exactly what you're asking, but here is a new fiddle using built-in SVGMatrix methods (http://jsfiddle.net/mmms5bsb/9/)